# Removing commas in VBA cell entry when select option is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to insert data from three different drop downs into my spreadsheet but I am having several difficulties. There are three drop downs called **cbo_fac1**, **cbo_fac2** and **cbo_fac3**. Here are the use cases:

**Use case 1**

```
cbo_fac1 - User selects 'No Preference' 
cbo_fac2 - User selects 'No Preference' 
cbo_fac3 - User selects 'No Preference'
```

In this case I only want No Preference to be inserted into the spreadsheet cell. This is being handled well so far.

**Use case 2 & 3**

```
cbo_fac1 - User does not select 'No Preference' 
cbo_fac2 - User does not select 'No Preference' 
cbo_fac3 - User selects 'No Preference' 

cbo_fac1 - User does not select 'No Preference' 
cbo_fac2 - User selects 'No Preference' 
cbo_fac3 - User selects 'No Preference'
```

In both cases I want 'No Preference to be skipped and only the values which are not `No Preference` to be inserted.

I have attempted this but unfortunately the system inserts commas which I would like to omit. So instead of having entries like `PC,DVD,` or `,DVD,PC` if the user selects the `No Preference` option, I would like to neaten it up and have it look like `PC, DVD` or `DVD, PC` to remove the comma associated with the blank entry.

I hope my explanation is clear enough, I included code below to show what I've accomplished so far.

```
 If Me.cbo_fac1 <> "No preference" Then
    cbo_fac1Entry = Me.cbo_fac1.Value
    Else
    cbo_fac1Entry = ""
    End If
    If Me.cbo_fac2 <> "No preference" Then
    cbo_fac2Entry = Me.cbo_fac2.Value
    Else
    cbo_fac2Entry = ""
    End If
    If Me.cbo_fac3 <> "No preference" Then
    cbo_fac3Entry = Me.cbo_fac3.Value
    Else
    cbo_fac3Entry = ""
    End If

    cbo_facEntry = cbo_fac1Entry & "," & cbo_fac2Entry & "," & cbo_fac3Entry

    If cbo_facEntry = ",," Then
    cbo_facEntry = "No Preference"
    Else
    End If

    rng1.Offset(1, 13) = cbo_facEntry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
If cbo_facEntry = ",," Then
cbo_facEntry = "No Preference"
Else
End If
```

I'd insert

```
cbo_facEntry = Trim(cbo_facEntry)

If Right(cbo_facEntry, 1) = "," Then
   cbo_facEntry = Left(cbo_facEntry, Len(cbo_facEntry) - 1)
End If

If Left(cbo_facEntry, 1) = "," Then
   cbo_facEntry = Right(cbo_facEntry, Len(cbo_facEntry) - 1)
End If

If InStr(1, cbo_facEntry, ",,") Then
   cbo_facEntry = Replace(cbo_facEntry, ",,", ", ")
End If
```

Covers case ",DVD,,PC,"

Comment: I corrected the syntax (was in hurry going to work and didn't debug the code). Everything should work now.